# asp.net code not working validation

Tags: validation

i can't figure out what exactly is wrong in this code. I an new to asp.net.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="^\d{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the control to validate property. Just set it like ControlToValidate ="txt". Like this

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ControlToValidate ="txt" ValidationExpression="^\d{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```